# Does a router use a separate DNS for DHCP requests when using a Pi-hole?

Tags: networking, router, dns, pihole

I am setting up a [Pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net) on my home network. My router has two locations which list an option to set a DNS. By default, one of these spaces is filled with the address of the router itself (`192.168.1.1`) the other is set to the upstream DNS of my ISP (`79.79.79.79`). I have been told that it is the first that I am supposed to change to the IP of my Pi-hole and to leave the other as is.

If my understanding is correct, does this mean that when a request is made, the Pi-hole receives the request, if it is local (i.e I want to access a NAS with hostname "Foo") then it will hand the request over to the routers DHCP server which will know what IP is assigned to that hostname as it has it's own DNS?

If, however, the request is external, then my Pi-hole will use the upstream DNS that is configured within the PiHole itself, and skip the the one specified in the router (`79.79.79.79`).

This appears to be working in theory, however, my question is, why am I able to ping devices by hostname from CMD on any Windows computer, if in theory the Pi-hole should stop this from working as the DHCP server is running on the router itself, and disabled on the Pi-hole?

How and where does DHCP come into this, and what part of my network is in charge of saying that the IP `x.x.x.x` belongs to hostname "Foo"?

Answer (score 1):

> Does a router use a separate DNS for DHCP requests when using a Pi-hole?

No ...

DHCP works like this:

- System needing an IP address sends a *broadcast* out of a NIC.
- A listening DHCP server receives the broadcast and responds.
- Some handshaking goes on, and the system needing an IP address gets a lease and also additional information called options.
- There's a lot of DHCP "options" - one of those is the IP address(es) of available DNS servers to use.

So until the 4th point above, there's no talking to anything but a DHCP server.  After the system gets DNS IPs from the DHCP server, *then* it can talk DNS.

> does this mean that when a request is made, the Pi-hole receives the request, if it is local (i.e I want to access a NAS with hostname "Foo") then it will hand the request over to the routers DHCP server which will know what IP is assigned to that hostname as it has it's own DNS?

I think the Pi-Hole uses `dnsmasq` - this is a small program that answers DNS requests - it can directly be configured with and respond to custom IP to domain mappings for local systems like your NAS, and can hand other DNS requests off to anything else.

That "anything else" is probably something that processes all the filters and then if something is not blocked, it will forward it to your ISP DNS or other external DNS you specify (like Google, etc.).

> why am I able to ping devices by hostname from CMD on any Windows computer

Windows can use [NetBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS) to resolve computer names, as well as DNS.  This is an older peer-to-peer protocol from the late 80's/early 90's that's from the days before TCP/IP wasn't an automatic given on PCs.  This protocol can function with or without a central WINS server.  This shouldn't be escaping your LAN.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive reply, I believe I am beginning to understand it now. Just to clarify - is the PiHole (once it's done its filtering) capable of bypassing the router from that point onwards and specifying the upstream DNS - I am just worried that it is somehow still using the mystery other box (the one by default set to my ISP's DNS) and have also been told using this local hostnames won't be accesible...yet I've tested and they seem to be...How is the pihole dealing with local hostnames?

Comment: thank you for you sharing!